# Issue with menu on hover

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

Hi there is my client site, in which there is menu issue occurring on hover. The menu was doing well till yesterday but now when site viewer hover on menu item it hides.

Site is http://www.triptour.dk/.

Thank you

Comment: Following the link to the site, I couldn't see the menu issue. However I see a kind broken layout - with a form on top of everything else. Checking the console there is also a js error. Can you clarify what the issue is? As a tip, if everything was working fine till yesterday, recall what has changed since then, as this might be the cause of any issues.

Comment: Same result as @FFrewin mentioned. Maybe try clearing your browser and Joomla cache, then try again

Comment: the menu issue is resolved but not the js swipe function occur i dont know why but i think this is due to the updating of the gruemenu . And there is a confilct with js

Comment: console showing an error here $(window).touchwipe({